# Reference a textFrame in InDesign by part of its name

Tags: javascript, reference, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I've run into an interesting quandary:  How can I reference a specific textFrame within InDesign CS6 if I only know PART of its name?  I have this bit of code:

```
var otherOverTable = document.layers.item("Spec Sheet").textFrames.item("<Other Printed ItemsYESNOOv>").tables.item(0);
var outputTable = document.layers.item("Spec Sheet").textFrames.item("<OUTPUT>").tables.item(0);
```

This code does not work.  I'm pretty certain it's due to the fact that the specific textFrames that have names surrounded by "<" and ">" signs are generated automatically by the text within those frames.

Beyond just renaming those textFrame objects before running the script, what can I do?  Is there some way I could reference the first one, for example, by saying something like, "Get the textFrame which has 'Other' as part of its name"?  I cannot reference it by index number as that will be different each time I run the script.

### Edit

I've got this bit of code to work, thankfully:

```
var otherOverTextFrame = findTextFrame(document, "Other");
var outputTextFrame = findTextFrame(document, "OUTPUT");

function findTextFrame(document, searchStr) {
var textFramesArray = document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();
for (var i = 0; i < textFramesArray.length; i++) {
    if (textFramesArray[i].tables.item(0).isValid) {
        if (textFramesArray[i].tables.item(0).cells.item(0).contents.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {
            return textFramesArray[i];
        }
    }
}
}
```

This returns an `[object TextFrame]`.  I think that's what I need, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference it.  For example, I need to change the contents of a certain cell within the table within that textFrame.  This code, however, does not work:

```
var otherOverTable = document.layers.item("Spec Sheet").otherOverTextFrame.tables.item(0);
```

How do I go about getting over this last hurdle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  That bit of code I referenced earlier got me 90% of the way there, but I completely forgot the fact that, once I have the textFrame object, I no longer needed to reference any of the hierarchy above it.  Thus, this following code is what will work (The nested `if` statement is due to the fact that some textFrames don't have a table):

```
var otherOverTable = findTextFrame(document, "Other").tables.item(0);
var outputTable = findTextFrame(document, "OUTPUT").tables.item(0);

function findTextFrame(document, searchStr) {
    var textFramesArray = document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < textFramesArray.length; i++) {
        if (textFramesArray[i].tables.item(0).isValid) {
            if (textFramesArray[i].tables.item(0).cells.item(0).contents.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {
                return textFramesArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all of your help steering me in the right direction, dln385!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a TextFrame that contains the word "Other", you might try something like this:

```
app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "Other";
var textArray = document.findText();
var textFrame = textArray[0].parentTextFrames[0];
```

If you want to find a TextFrame whose name contains "Other", then you'll probably need to search for it yourself:

```
var textFrame = findTextFrame("Other");

function findTextFrame(searchStr) {
    var textFramesArray = document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < textFramesArray.length; i++) {
        var textFrame = textFramesArray[i];
        if (textFrame.name.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {
            return textFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that either approach could find multiple matches, and its only returning the first match.

**Edit:** What output do you get from this?

```
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "Other";
var textArray = document.findGrep();
$.writeln("Found " + textArray.length + " matches.");
for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    $.writeln("\nMatch " + (i + 1) + ":");
    var text = textArray[i];
    $.writeln("Contents: " + text.contents.toString());
    $.writeln("Number of parent text frames: " + text.parentTextFrames.length);
    $.writeln("Type of parent: " + text.parent.constructor.name);
}
```

Comment: I've tried many variations on your second example, but I'm afraid that just won't work.  Any textFrame that hasn't been given an explicit name is automatically given a sort of proxy name in "&lt;" and "&gt;" symbols.  Sadly, even these "proxy" names cannot be referenced in the script, it seems.  Whenever I run a `$.writeln(textFramesArray[i].toString());` inside of the `for` loop, I only get `[object TextFrame]` as a result.  And when I run `$.writeln(textFramesArray[i].name);`, I get a blank line in the console.  That tells me that all of the textFrames are unnamed.

Comment: Try using `$.writeln(textFramesArray[i].contents.toString());` to get more useful information. If the TextFrames are indeed unnamed, then you'll want to use the first approach in the answer.

Comment: Tried your first example, as well as several variations on it, without success.  The ESTK even gives me a debug error on the last line, saying `undefined is not an object`.  Wow, this is turning out to be much more difficult than I at first thought.

Comment: Alright, your `$.writeln(textFramesArray[i].contents.toString());` method is getting closer.  Unfortunately, if the textFrame contains a table, then it returns no text, it seems.  If I could have it search inside tables inside of each textFrame for the search string, then I think that just might do it.  Probably would require a nested `if` statement, I suppose.

Comment: The output from that block of code was not encouraging: `Found 0 matches.
Result: undefined`